# QGIS to .DXF export: labels do not appear

Tags: qgis, labeling, export, dxf

I have been trying to export a shp layer in QGIS 2.18 to dxf with some labels using the export to DXF tool included in QGIS, but somehow, the labels won't appear on the export. I have tried changing font, symbology mode, symbology scale, encoding, etc. but still haven't found what is wrong!

I have run out of ideas, is there some option I may have forgotten or a parameter I need to activate?

[image: What I have in QGIS]

[image: What I get in dxf format]

Comment: We use Arc2CAD if we need to include labels in the .dxf.

Comment: https://gisforthought.com/gis-to-cad-using-ogr2ogr-part-3-point-annotation-to-text-in-cad/